# QualityToolsPackage failed to load in build?

Tags: visual-studio, build, bamboo, devenv

I am using Bamboo [from Altassian] and it uses the devenv.com builder to build solution files. Currently, I seem to be getting a "false" error in my builds - that I've tried to solve by myself but just can't - so I thought I would ask.

Each build succeeds normally - without errors stemming from code - but seems to instead give this error

> Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestCaseManagement.QualityToolsPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.TestCaseManagement, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' failed to load.

I've no idea why this is causing problems in the devenv.com environment and I can't figure out either how to "ignore" this error by some build command?

Comment: I ran into the same issue. Reading other posts on the net it seems to work using devenv.exe instead of devenv.com, however, this is not an acceptable solution since all errors are ignored. Steve Baker claimed to have found a good workaround - unfortunately the blog post is offline: http://stevebaker.net/?p=64

Comment: Blog appears to be back online.

Comment: Can you add a visual-studio tag or something similar please?

Answer (score 2):

Try this ( from MSFT support )

Can you check if the dll is in the global assembly cache (open a VS 2010 command prompt

```
(Start | All Programs | Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 | Visual Studio Tools))
```

Type in

```
Gacutil –l > list.txt

Notepad list.txt
```

Do you see an entry like

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.TestCaseManagement, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL
```

If so, from the same command prompt, run fuslogvw, go to settings, select log bind failures to disk, select ok

Run your command line

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com /Build "Release|Mixed Platforms" "D:\Builds\19\Test VizXView\VizXView v1.8 Test Release Build - Weekly\Sources\VizXView v1.8\VizXView 1.8.sln"
```

Click on the refresh button in fuslogvw.  Do we get any bind errors?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue related to running unit tests on a build server that was using devenv.exe (not devenv.com). I had a premium VS installed on the build server but I'd written the unit tests with ultimate (which 'has' load testing, even tho I'd not used it). I used fusion viewer to work out that the missing dll was LoadTest.dll which I copied from my laptop to the buildserver, I also removed references in my solution that were in version control to: *.vsmdi and *.testsettings (they're deprecated) and I removed from the build def a reference to a .testsettings file.

My guess would be that even though I wasn't running a load unit test the build agent was trying to load the LoadTest libs just in case. Hope that helps

edit ---

ok, my own problem here was that I've got both vs2010 and vs2013 on my laptop. When I added the first test project to my VS2010 solution, the project added actually has a dependency on the 2013 version of the UnitTestFramework.dll. My build server only has vs2010 on it so I got the missing assembly error. Switching the reference to the 2010 version fixed this.